# How to check enum type in Swift in a more concise way?

Tags: swift, enums

This is how I check enum type. Is it a way not do it with `switch` but shorter?

```swift
if let i = instance as? DataToValidate {
    switch i {
       case .object:
        return true
       default:
        return false
    }
} else {
    return false
}
```

And my type:

```swift
public enum DataToValidate {
    case object(JSONObject)
    case array(JSONArray)
    case string(String)
}
```

Comment: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-if-case-let/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` and `guard` statements allow you to use pattern matching.

```
if case DataToValidate.object = instance {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
```

If you want to use the associated value, you can bind it:

```
if case DataToValidate.object(let object) = instance {
    return object
} else {
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most succinct now:

```swift
if case DataToValidate.object = instance {
  return true
}

return false
```

[Might become better](https://forums.swift.org/t/proposal-draft-for-is-case-pattern-match-boolean-expressions/58260/):

```swift
instance is case DataToValidate.object
```